# :nth-last-child(1 of .class) not working in Chrome?

Tags: css

It made my day yesterday when I found out about `:nth-last-child(1 of .class)` yesterday! The idea is to **select the last occurrence of an element with a certain class**.

I had tested in my go-to-browser (Safari) and today I'm trying it out in Chrome and it is NOT working!

Is this amazing piece of technology Safari-only or am I doing something wrong? Is there an alternative for Chrome?

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 25px;
  animation: animation 1s;
}


div:nth-last-child(1 of .solid) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="solid">Solid 1</div>
<div class="overlay">Overlay 1</div>
<div class="solid">Solid 2</div>
<div class="overlay">Overlay 2</div>
<div class="solid">Solid 3 (<- expected to be lightblue)</div>
<div class="overlay">Overlay 3</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Browser_compatibility According to this, it only works on safari for the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your conclusion is true. The `of <selector>` feature is not yet widely supported. See the MDN browser compatibility table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child

Comment: Urgh, sometimes it's hard living in a bubble of a Apple-goodness.. Thanks though..  

Answer (score 0):

If you know your structure always will be

```
<div class="solid">...</div>
<div class="overlay">...</div>
<div class="solid">..</div>
```

Then you can just target the last element -1 with the following:

```
div:nth-last-child(2) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't though. There can be any number and order of `solid` and `overlay` classes..